# How to get the WS URL from the Web Service Method code

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, url

I've inherited from a another team a WCF Web Service devloped on .net framework 3.5.
When installed on a Sandbox, the WS URL looks like this:

URL: https://<*EnvironmentName*>/fr/webservices/<*someWebServiceName*>.svc

What I was requested is to get that URL from the Web Service Method code during the WS execution ( runtime ). Do you have any idea?

I would tend to think there should be a environment variable which can be easily used to get the URL. Any contribution will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question to be more clear on what you actually want? Thanks

Comment: @MichelZ: I've re-writed the issue. Thanks for your heads up.

Answer (score 4):

The OperationContext is available and should provide what you're looking for, specifically:

```
OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var context = OperationContext.Current;
var requestedUrl =  context.IncomingMessageHeaders.To.PathAndQuery;
```

Comment: Thank you MicehelZ. Your details were helpful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[**Update**]: With the help provided by @MichelZ, I've been able to address my question. Here's the code:

```
var context = OperationContext.Current;
string requestedUrl = context.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri.ToString();
```

Thank you all!